# Want Clarification for Program Loop (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, program-entry-point

So I was wondering if someone would be able to help shed a little light for me on something I am working on in Python.

I am creating a program with a Tkinter GUI interface that interacts with a Serial device, and an ADC chip to measure voltage.  I want to make sure I properly understand how I'm building the main program loop to keep everything running smoothly.  I'm going to lay out how I think the program should run, if anyone has any corrections please throw them at me.

1. Program is run, GUI Interface initializes
2. User presses a button
3. send signal of button through serial
4. measure/display voltage levels
5. periodically update voltage display
6. if button is pressed, return to step 3

Now I know to run my Tkinter GUI I set up `mainloop()` as the last line of code.  Now my question is simply, is that all I will need?  Will `mainloop()` continually update while it waits for another button press, or will I essentially have to creatre an update method that cycles through everything until another button is pressed?

Comment: _"or will I essentially have to create an update method that cycles through everything until another button is pressed?"_ - Not all. That's why you use `Tk().mainloop()`. `tkinter` does this for you. All you are expected to do is implement the functionality that should happen when your button is pressed. `tkinter` will listen for the button press for you.

Comment: @ChristianDean you should post this as an answer. well explained.

Comment: @ChristianDean So if I want the program to be updating the voltage every second after the button is pressed (while waiting for another one to be pressed) I don't need a `while buttonPressed` loop or anything?

Comment: @Skitzafreak Yes, that is correct. You simply need to let `tkinter` know what you want to happen when it "hears" a button press. `tkinter` will do all the event-loop listening for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will mainloop() continually update while it waits for another button press, or will I essentially have to creatre an update method that cycles through everything until another button is pressed?

Not all. That's why you are using `tk.Tk().mainloop()`. tkinter does this for you. All you are expected to do is implement the functionality that should happen when your button is pressed. tkinter will listen for the button press.